# Netsuite:- how to extract Saved Searches & Reports data using SuiteAnalytics Connect Service (ODBC)?

Tags: odbc, integration, analytics, netsuite, saved-searches

As per documentation:- the SuiteAnalytics Connect Service enables you to run queries against two different data sources:

1. NetSuite.com data source – Uses the only schema available up to 2018.2 to retrieve data.
2. NetSuite2.com data source – Uses the new schema available from 2019.1 for SuiteAnalytics Connect shared with the SuiteAnalytics Workbook, saved searches and reports.

While setting up the Suite Analytics connect ODBC driver, I selected NetSuite2.com as the data source. However, I don't see any saved searches created in Netsuite UI, even after sharing that with the specific user/role. Though, I could see many other tables (as in Analytics Browser) and custom datasets etc.

[image: Here's the table list fetched from NetSuite2.com data source]

It says that this new data source (Netsuite2.com) applies role-based access restrictions and that Users can query only data that they can access in the SuiteAnalytics Workbook user interface.

Then, how do I access the saved searches & reports created in NetSuite UI via Connect (ODBC) service ? Or it only allows to access saved workbooks and  datasets ?

Looking only via ODBC method, not SuiteScript/SOAP/RESTful Webservices/API's.